# Auth Guard in Angular without using LocalStorage or Cookie

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing an auth guard in Angular but instead of accessing localstorage or cookies to check if the user is authenticated, I have an API endpoints that returns `200 OK` if there is a httponly cookie containing the JWT attached to the request and `401 Unauthorized` otherwise.

Here is what I have tried

```
// auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.httpClient.post('/users/login', { username, password });
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    this.httpClient.get('/users/check').subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        return true;
      },
      error: () => {
        return false;
      },
    });

    return false;
  }
}
```

```
// auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/auth/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{ path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent }],
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The problem happens after the user has logged on and the authentication cookie has been set, the `isLoggedIn()` function still returns false and thus redirects the user back to the login page. My speculation is that it has something to do with me handling the observable from `httpclient` wrongly and causing it to `return false;` before the request is completed?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic issue of async handling, and some function scoping Understanding...

when you do this, two main issues can be seen:

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    this.httpClient.get('/users/check').subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        return true; // issue 02
      },
      error: () => {
        return false;  // issue 02
      },
    });

    return false; // issue 01
  }
```

- Issue 01: Your function is only/always returning `false`, as this is the only return statement in the scope of the `isLoggedIn` function. (classic async issue)
- Issue 02: Your callback functions withing the subscription are called, but their returned value is not being used. (issue with the understanding of function scoping). The issue is that the `return`'s I marked as "Issue 02" belong to the scope of the subscription callbacks, and not to the scope of the `isLoggedIn` function.

to resolve this:

1. you should return the observable, converting the result to true/false with a pipe and not subscribe:

```
isLoggedIn() {
  return this.httpClient.get('/users/check').pipe(
    map(() => true),
    catchError(() => of(false))
  )
}
```

2. From your guard (where you have a similar problem as in your service), you also not subscribe, and trust that the subscription will be done by the caller of the Guard (angular internal):

```
canActivate() {
  return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(take(1), tap(loggedIn => {
    if (!loggedIn) this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me.

Inside isLoggedIn function:

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return this.httpClient.get('/users/check').subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            return true;
          },
          error: () => {
            return false;
          },
        });
      }
```

Inside canActivate Guard :

```
 canActivate(){
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(res => {
        if (!res) this.router.navigate(['login']);
        else return true;    
    });
 }
```